# I can't use slidetoggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

```
<body ng-controller="ChatController">
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-primary" id="container">
            <div class="panel-heading">Web Based Firebase Chat Application</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p ng-repeat="m in messages">{{m.message}} - {{m.date | date:'medium'}}</p>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Message here..." ng-model="messageText">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="send()">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#container").click(function () {
             $(this).next('#container').slideToggle("slow");
         }); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code currently says is: "When clicking #container, find the next element #container and toggle it".

That doesn't work, there is no other #container element beside the element with the id "container".

So just remove the .next('#container') part, and clicking the container will slideToggle it.

```
<body ng-controller="ChatController">
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-primary" id="container">
            <div class="panel-heading">Web Based Firebase Chat Application</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p ng-repeat="m in messages">{{m.message}} - {{m.date | date:'medium'}}</p>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Message here..." ng-model="messageText">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="send()">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#container").click(function () {
             $(this).slideToggle("slow");
         }); });
</script>
```

Also keep in mind, when hiding the container, you cant toggle (show it again) it, as its now completely hidden and not clickable at all.